# CPU utilization reaches 100% too often on grizzly http (REST) server - JAVA8

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, grizzly

We have a jersey rest server that uses a grizzly http server(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory). Recently we migrated from java7 to java8. 
Since then after serving requests smoothly for 1 hour or so, 
- CPU utilization of our machine goes to 100% (usually it is 5%, with very sparse peaks of 40%)
- all http requests to the server hang. 
- Server logs show no exceptions.
- Threads started by server keep doing their job and are not affected
- Apparently only the http interface seems to be broken.
Upon restarting server, the behavior goes away but shows up again an hour later.

When we migrated back to java7, server was behaving  well, and no issues.
For now we migrated to java7. But since we would like to move to java8 at some point in future,
- Has anyone seen this happening in their?
- Is there a way to debug this failure and get more debug information at grizzly http server level? 
(are there any command line flags to be passed to java -jar our_application_jar.jar command that can grab more debug information)
- Can any one explain the reason why our grizzly is behaving weirdly with java8?
- Can we suspect that JDK 1.8's NIO library is messing up with grizzly, but how can we conclude that?

Our machine/deployment details
- ubuntu, aws m1 large
- java application, run as unix service
- grizzly 2.8 (using grizzly http server)

Comment: I would say this sounds like an issue with the garbage collector (GC). Have you tried profiling the application? To gather further data?

Comment: I have experienced the same kind of issue, the problem was an infinite loop.

Comment: @pintxo: thank you for your quick reply,we tried running jar with option; java -Xmx2G -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -jar app.jar. Could please explain the profiling the app and we didnt find any useful info

Comment: @dounyy: our code contains no infinite loops

Comment: Try getting YourKit or VisualVM, are both excellent profilers.

Comment: I'd say the issue is much more likely to be with your code rather than with Grizzly. As others suggest, garbage collection is a possible cause although it should be using G1 by default and not do too many stop the world garbage collects. Use visualvm to track if you are leaking memory somehow or to profile where it is spending its cpu.

Comment: Have you tried to look at thread dump taken at these times? jps/jstack from command line. Very useful for identifying hot spots such as yours.

Comment: @bps: Nobody is dumb enough to put deliberately infinite loops in his code; by infinite loop I meant a while loop that, for a reason, never invalids its looping condition. These are often hard to find.

Comment: @bps as mentined by Mikkel Løkke try http://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: Not a grizzly user, but I've found a project of ours that locks up Netbeans during compilation under Java8 but compiles fine on Java7.  Have not located the exact problem yet, but you're not the only one with Java8 woes.  :-)

Comment: @bps does 100% CPU utilization remain even after you disconnect all the clients (pull out the network cable for example)? If yes - you can make several thread dumps (using jstack) to find out what exactly the threads are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JProfiler. It will help you figure out any performance and/or resource issues your software may have. It's free for a limited time (Should be enough to debug your software)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I thought it would be a good answer to "Is there a way to debug this failure and get more debug information at grizzly http server level?".